# How can I assign a value inside a loop?

Tags: python

I want to assign a value in the condition statement of the loop. Is there any way I can do that?

I want to try something like:

```
while(p=raw_input("enter the value")):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve something like that with the following code

```
while True:
    p = raw_input("Enter the value':")
    if value == '1':
        break
```

replace value == '1' with your termination condition